# Scrape IMDB reviews and rating using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape reviews and rating information for specific movies on IMDB. Here is my code for scraping rating:

```
 try:
     rating = review.find_element_by_css_selector('[class = "rating-other-user-rating"]')
     star_rating.append(rating.text)
 except:
     rating = None
```

Here is the HTML

```
<span class="rating-other-user-rating">
        <svg class="ipl-icon ipl-star-icon  " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
            <path d="M12 17.27L18.18 21l-1.64-7.03L22 9.24l-7.19-.61L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21z"></path>
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
        </svg>
            <span>7</span><span class="point-scale">/10</span>
        </span>
```

Questions:

1. I need to retrieve "7" from the above HTML. What am I missing in the code to retrieve it. I think the problem is that the rating is located in a span tag with no classes or ID, and I can't figure it yet I would really appreciate the help. Thanks
2. How can I scrape a certain number of reviews from IMDB? For example, if I want to scrape just 50 reviews. I tried using the code below but that doesn't work. The program continues executing and doesn't stop at 50:

   ```
     nextbutton = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'ipl- load-more__button')))

     if len(movie_title) == 50: # movie_title is the number of reviews titles scraped so far. 50 is ideal
        break

     nextbutton.click()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. The rating score of ***7*** is within a `<span>` and is the second descendant of it's ancestor `<span>`

```
<span class="rating-other-user-rating">
    <svg class="ipl-icon ipl-star-icon  " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
        <path d="M12 17.27L18.18 21l-1.64-7.03L22 9.24l-7.19-.61L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21z"></path>
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
    </svg>
    <span>7</span>
    <span class="point-scale">/10</span>
</span>
```

---

### Solution

To extract the text ***7*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.rating-other-user-rating span:first-of-type"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='rating-other-user-rating']//span[not(@class)]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for the suggestion. As you can tell from my code, I'm trying to retrieve rating for different movie reviews. I tried running the above code using CSS_SELECTOR, and I did receive the value within the span but it's the same value for all reviews.

Comment: The _CSS_SELECTOR_ is based on the HTML you provided. I'm not sure about other HTMLs.

Comment: Got it. Looks like things have worked out! The following code solved the problem:
rating = review.find_element_by_css_selector('.rating-other-user-rating span')
star_rating.append(rating.text)

Comment: Glad to be able to help you